# TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got list

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

I was trying to run the code of diffusion probabilistic models given [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/annotated-diffusion). While saving the images of the reverse diffusion model using this code block:

```
from torchvision.utils import save_image

epochs = 100

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      batch_size = batch["pixel_values"].shape[0]
      batch = batch["pixel_values"].to(device)

      # Algorithm 1 line 3: sample t uniformally for every example in the batch
      t = torch.randint(0, timesteps, (batch_size,), device=device).long()

      loss = p_losses(model, batch, t, loss_type="huber")

      if step % 100 == 0:
        print("Loss:", loss.item())

      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      # save generated images
      if step != 0 and step % save_and_sample_every == 0:
        milestone = step // save_and_sample_every
        batches = num_to_groups(4, batch_size)
        all_images_list = list(map(lambda n: sample(model, batch_size=n, channels=channels), batches))
        all_images = torch.cat(all_images_list, dim=0)
        all_images = (all_images + 1) * 0.5
        save_image(all_images, str(results_folder / f'sample-{milestone}.png'), nrow = 6)
```

I get an error saying: TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got list.
This comes on the line `all_images = torch.cat(all_images_list, dim=0)`.

I have understood that this comes as `torch.cat` expected a tensor but `all_images_list` is a list.
I tried all means but could not find an alternative way to save the generated images without getting this error.
I shall be grateful if the community could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
def p_sample_loop(model, shape):
    device = next(model.parameters()).device

    b = shape[0]
    # start from pure noise (for each example in the batch)
    img = torch.randn(shape, device=device)
    imgs = []

    for i in tqdm(reversed(range(0, timesteps)), desc='sampling loop time step', total=timesteps):
        img = p_sample(model, img, torch.full((b,), i, device=device, dtype=torch.long), i)
        imgs.append(img.cpu().numpy())
    return imgs
```

with

```
def p_sample_loop(model, shape):
    device = next(model.parameters()).device

    b = shape[0]
    # start from pure noise (for each example in the batch)
    img = torch.randn(shape, device=device)
    imgs = []
    
    for i in tqdm(reversed(range(0, timesteps)), desc='sampling loop time step', total=timesteps):
        img = p_sample(model, img, torch.full((b,), i, device=device, dtype=torch.long), i)
        imgs.append(img.cpu())
    return imgs
```

and also replace

```
all_images_list = list(map(lambda n: sample(model, batch_size=n, channels=channels), batches))
all_images = torch.cat(all_images_list, dim=0)
```

with

```
all_images_list = list(map(lambda n: sample(model, image_size = image_size, batch_size=n, channels=channels), batches))
all_images = torch.cat(all_images_list[0], dim=0)
```

You would find the generated images in the `./results` folder